Argocd token expiry time configuration
I have configured SSO in ArgoCD using SAML(Dex). Everything seems fine except the token expiry time. The current validity is 24 hours. I want to reduce it to 30 minutes. Is there any way we can configure the ArgoCD token expiry?
Any help would be much appreciated!
